# How can i send post request with parameters and fetching response - React Native

Tags: api, react-native

I want to send request to server with parameters from input text and fetch the response on new page, I tried many tutorials but none of them worked. I tried this

```
  constructor() {
    super();
      this.state={
        username:'',
        password:'',
        kode_ujian:''
      }
  }

  updateValue(text, field) {
    if(field=='username')
    {
      this.setState({
        username:text,
      })
    }
    else if(field=='password')
    {
      this.setState({
        password:text,
      })
    }
    else if(field=='kode_ujian')
    {
      this.setState({
        kode_ujian:text,
      })
    }
  }
```

and this

```
submit() {
    let collection={}
    collection.username=this.state.username,
    collection.email=this.state.password,
    collection.kode_ujian=this.state.kode_ujian

    fetch('https://ffst.my.id/onclass/index.php/api/list_jawaban', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'text/html',
        'Content-Type': 'text/html',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: 'this.state.username',
        password: 'this.state.password',
        kode_ujian: 'this.state.kode_ujian'
      })
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((text) => {
        return text;
        console.warn(text);
      })
    });
  }


render() {

    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
              <TextInput style={styles.inputBox}underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)' onChangeText={(text) => this.updateValue(text, 'username')}
                placeholder="Username" placeholderTextColor = "#ffffff"/>
              <TextInput style={styles.inputBox}underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)' onChangeText={(text) => this.updateValue(text, 'password')}
                placeholder="Password" placeholderTextColor = "#ffffff" secureTextEntry={true}/>
              <TextInput style={styles.inputBox}underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)' onChangeText={(text) => this.updateValue(text, 'kode_ujian')}
                placeholder="Kode Ujian" placeholderTextColor = "#ffffff"/>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.submit()} style={styles.button}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Submit</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                        );
  }
}
```

The first code is the code I've tried before, and the second one are my input text, any solutions?

Comment: Your code seems fine. 
The most common way is `fetch` method. You can also use [axios][1].
  [1]: https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/getting-started-with-axios-166cb0035237

Comment: what is your problem exactly? the fetch method?

Comment: sending request using the result from input text, and  fetching the response from it,

Comment: So you need a form, for example, the user fills it out and then submit it to a post request. Is this right?

Comment: yeepp, and fetching the result from the response, can you provide me  a tutorial or something? thankss

Comment: The main references are =>
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch
https://github.com/axios/axios

Answer (score 0):

This is a Post Request` Example with axios:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class PersonList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: '',
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const user = {
      name: this.state.name
    };

    axios.post(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`, { user })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Person Name:
            <input type="text" name="name" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </label>
          <button type="submit">Add</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And an example with `fetch`:

```
// App.js
import React, { Component } from ‘react’;
import ‘./App.css’;

export default class App extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={ name:’’, email:’’ }
    }
    handleChange = event =>{
        this.setState({ [event.target.name]:event.target.value })
    }
    handleSubmit = event =>{
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(“User name : “ + this.state.name)
        console.log(“User Email : “ + this.state.email)
        const url =”https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/”
            const data = { name:this.state.name, email:this.state.email }
        fetch(url, { method: ‘POST’, // or ‘PUT’
        body: JSON.stringify(data), // data can be `string` or {object}!
            headers:{ ‘Content-Type’: ‘application/json’ } })
    .then(res => res.json())
            .catch(error => console.error(‘Error:’, error))
    .then(response => console.log(‘Success:’, response)); }
    render(){
        return(
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input type=”text” name=”name” onChange={this.handleChange} />
                <input type=”email” name=”email” onChange={this.handleChange} />
                <input type=”submit” value=”Add user” /> 
            </form> 
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I JSON.stringify(user) in axios example?

Comment: @DevAS nope, it is an out of box feature! it is already done by axios

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed two aspects that may be causing issues.

First, when you create the body you have encapsulated the state variable in quotes, meaning it will take the string 'this.state.username' rather than the variable it represents. Try set your body like this instead:

```
body: JSON.stringify({
    username: this.state.username,
    password: this.state.password,
    kode_ujian: this.state.kode_ujian
})
```

Second, you placed your `.then` statements after the `JSON.stringify` which does not return a promise. Move your `.then` statements to the end of your `fetch` query which will pass in the response correctly. At the moment, even if your response is being fetched correctly, due to the incorrect location of your `.then` handler statements, the result isn't being handled at all.

If you change your `submit` method to this it should work properly.

```
submit() {
  let collection={}
  collection.username=this.state.username,
  collection.email=this.state.password,
  collection.kode_ujian=this.state.kode_ujian

  fetch('https://ffst.my.id/onclass/index.php/api/list_jawaban', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'text/html',
      'Content-Type': 'text/html',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      username: this.state.username,
      password: this.state.password,
      kode_ujian: this.state.kode_ujian
    })
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((json) => {
    console.log(json);
    return json;
  })
}
```

I also changed the `response.text()` to `response.json()` which will turn it into a JS object and make accessing the results much easier.

Then as a separate comment, your `updateValue` function can be heavily streamlined into the following function:

```
updateValue(text, field) {
    this.setState({ [field]: value });
}
```